# Firefox button and text input bug

Tags: html, css, firefox, button, input

I have this really weird problem, button and input have a same CSS (except background), but Firefox renders those differently. There are no problems in IE or Chrome.

```
#searchInput {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
#searchButton {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 4px auto;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I have also included container CSS, where they both are.

```
.section {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.toggleIcon {
    width: 28px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='search' class='section'> <a href="#sidebarNav" class='toggle'><img class = 'toggleIcon' src = 'img/icons/glyphicons_158_show_lines.png' alt = 'Open navigation'></a>
    <img id='logo' src='img/logo.png'>
    <form id='searchForm'>
        <input type='text' id='searchInput' name='searchInput'>
        <button type='submit' id='searchButton' name='searchButton' value='Search'>
            <img src='img/icons/glyphicons_027_search.png' alt='Search'>
        </button>
    </form>
    <div id='searchResults'></div>
</div>
```

NB! I use PageSlide for navigation and search is using AJAX

Comment: Provide your HTML code.

Comment: With a basic example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLyBR/)) with *your* code I get the same results in Firefox & Crome.

Can you specify more clearly where and how they *"renders those differently"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment...

> *Margin doesn't cause my problems, problem is that input is much wider
>   and higher*

You have to add **`box-sizing:`**`border-box` property to your `input#searchInput`

Like:

```
#searchInput {
    ....
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
}
```

### Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XLyBR/1/

Comment: Thank you very much, I already used * { box-sizing: border-box} but I didn't know that Firefox don't give a damn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your margin differs in the searchInput and searchButton css classes

Also what about the default css line-height on these elements - do they differ - try specifying line-height.

Wing

BTW - it would help if you tell us how the rendering differs

Comment: Margin doesn't cause my problems, problem is that input is much wider and higher