# Weird position issue w/ custom styled select in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, select

I am trying to obtain a pure CSS select input with an arrow. All is well except Firefox is causing some weird issue and pushing the arrow past the width of the box.

You can see it here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/xvvfgv3k (Please view in a FF browser)

Is this some sort of bug? When viewing the css in Firebug to try and fix the problem, it fixes itself and displays how it should. Really weird. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try making your `select` element relative and adjusting the `right` property on your `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

Try this

```
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  font-size: 14px;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  padding:10px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #bec1c3;
  border-radius:0;
  background: #fff;
  color:#888;
  line-height: 1;
  outline:none;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  position: relative;
}

span.select {
    position:relative;
    padding: 9px 0;
}

span.select:after {
    content:'';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 4px 0 4px;
    border-color: #bec1c3 transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 14px;
    pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

span.select:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    right: 6px;
    top: 0;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: This did not work because I am using the :before & :after elements to create the arrow which cannot be used on select elements.

Comment: @ftntravis sorry, what browser version are you on for ff?

Comment: The latest version 25.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Saucelabs shows the following browsers also show the bug you refer to :

```
   1. Firefox 25 on windows7
   2. Firefox 20 on windows7
   3. Firefox 10 on windows7
   4. Firefox 25 on Linux
```

Does this link help?
[Firefox button and text input bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054612/firefox-button-and-text-input-bug)